# Java Benchmark for Graph

Tags: java, benchmarking

I am looking for a benchmark/some tests for my tool that was written in Java to simplify graph structure for traversal.

The benchmark should create some graphs. Each node in a graph has the same type(e.g., each node's class extends/implements the same abstract class/interface), and the abstract method is invoked frequently.

For example, class `Object` is not suitable, although it is the base of all Java classes, because the methods, (e.g., `toString()` and `equal()`) might be not frequently. It is something

```
interface INodeInter{
   public someType nodeMethod(args);
}
```

and all graph nodes implements `INodeInter`. It is also OK the graph becomes a tree or a linked list.

I have looked Dacapo and Computer Language Benchmark Game, both are not suitable either..

Comment: Normally you *write* test for your tool, not *look* for them.

Comment: Yes. It is true in most of times. Yet, I have to present my work for the academic, and my own tests are not convincing, as others ague that the tests are specified designed for my implementation, rather than general.